# How to replicate this (pictured) layout using css or bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

## My Problem

I am new to Bootstrap. My boss wants me to replicate the following screen ( or as close as possible ):

### Desired Layout

[image: Desired Layout]

I have tried to do this myself using:

```
<div class = "row"> 

and

<div class = "col-lg-x">
```

... but I can't get the rows and columns right! So frustrating. I have tried and tried and tried.

Does anyone have any ideas how I would replicate the following layout easily?

Thank you so much for looking at my problem.

Regards,

John

Comment: If you are having a hard time figuring out the layout you could review the [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) system and build out the rows and columns you need. If thats too complex you could also look at [purchasing a BS themes](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/) that closely resemebles the layout you want.

Comment: Well, @crazymatt, I didn't think I was having a hard time figuring it out, it just wasn't displaying properly. Apparently I misinterpreted the Bootstrap class [col-size-num]. After trial and error, the solution became clear to me.

It's so simple I feel like a dummy. For newbies like me, for each screen size, it must equal 12... so for small devices, 2 columns 3 and 9. For medium devices, 6 and 6. So simple, so awesome! 

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6" >
      Crazymatt
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6">
      Was Here 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the way that you have put your code on to SO however it should look something like this

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  4
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
    12
   <div class="row">
    <div class-"col-sm-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: You may also wish to take a look at nesting to help you achieve this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Yes, I was mis-understanding a fundamental grid component class, and how it worked. After reading through the link above, I figured out I was not properly applying the breakpoints for different screen sizes. I do thank you for pointing that out, as I somehow missed it.  [ and to the person who voted down a well articulated, valid question such as this for someone who wants to learn (StackO's reason for living right?) -- to you I say, rather than haphazardly voting down new users, why not try helping them with constructive pointers??. Anyways, thanks @Jenko.

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful!